SSRS errors using stored procedure, but allows the identical script to work
I have other reports, using other stored procedures on other databases, working without difficulty.  I was even able to create the desired report by putting all of the script in the SSRS report, instead of in a stored procedure.
For ease of maintenance, I prefer to have script in stored procedures, so it can be updated without editing the SSRS report, but, in this instance, the stored procedure works from SSMS, but I get "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed." when I tell the report to use the stored procedure, instead of script.

I hate mysteries, so I hope someone can tell my why this error occurs.  The fact that the script runs, from the same report, proves the connection is fine and my internet search failed to find an answer.
Thank you,
Andy

Does the sp return results when run in SSMS? The account that runs the sp from reporting services, does it have execute permission on that sp?

Yes, the procedure runs fine in SSMS and its script runs fine from SSRS.  The connection error only occurs when calling the procedure from SSRS.

what about the execute permission on the procedure?

I was running under windows authentication and I have full admin access.  I had the same thought, so I gave all users access to execute the stored procedure and error remained.

what if you delete and recreate your datasource? If you havn't tried that already!

I went even further and created another report from scratch, including deleting and recreating the procedure.
